# Sqlite (within SqliteStudio): invalid command name "parray"

Tags: sqlite, tcl, create-function

I am discovering writing functions in TCL for Sqlite (https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/wiki/ScriptingTcl).

I wanted to play a basic exemple found in the official page of sqlite(http://sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html):

```
db eval {SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY MyID} values { 
    parray values
    puts ""
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error while requesting the database « -- » : invalid command name "parray"
```

Help is very welcome :)

Comment: Don't confuse: SqliteStudio's Tcl is not standard Tcl (see my answer). And, in addition, the Sqlite procs of SqliteStudio are not those provided by tclsqlite, they just mimick them. You can't simply port examples from the one to the other and expect them work, which is not very intuitive, agreed.

Comment: How did you manage to run `sqlite3` command in `tcl`? I still cannot on my Linux...

Comment: Alex, my answer might be stupidly simple as I don't play anymore with sqlite and tcl, but on most linux you have a package for SQLite 3 Tcl bindings. For debian, it is libsqlite3-tcl that you can install by doiing (as root) "apt-get install libsqlite3-tcl"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SqliteStudio does not seem to fully initialise Tcl, as you would expect it from a non-embedded installation:

> Using external Tcl packages or modules is not possible, because Tcl
>   interpreters are not initialized with "init.tcl".

See [Wiki](https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/wiki/ScriptingTcl).

### Background

Standard Tcl sources `init.tcl`, early as part of an Tcl interpreter's initialisation. `init.tcl`, in turn, registers a number of Tcl procs for [autoloading](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/library.htm#M8). `parray` is one of those lazily acquired procs.

### Ways forward

I am not familiar with SqliteStudio. Why not stick with sqlite's standard [Tcl frontend](https://www.sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html), which gives you full Tcl and comes with Tcl distributions free house? But this certainly depends on your requirements.

That said, you could attempt to force-load `init.tcl` in SqliteStudio's embedded Tcl, but I don't know (and can't test) whether the distribution has not pruned these scripts or whether they were effectively relocated. From the top of my head (untested):

```
source [file join $tcl_library init.tcl]
# ...
db eval {SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY MyID} values { 
    parray values
    puts ""
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it does not really save my problem at first look, but at least I undertand the problem: I got the idea that I could not load external libraries, but I was thinking parray as fully internal to tcl. I will explore what you propose in your answer.

Comment: What I would like to provide, is a complex checking function which would be directly launchable from the database admin tool: I though to write it in tcl because it would both work in this sqlitestudio tool and potentially could be run from another tool (command line?). In fact I would like an extension to the database, I know this is not fully possible but I try to find a workaround. I have seen the possibility to write extension in C but I fear the problem of portability and easyness to use for the client.

Comment: Well, as long as you take care and strictly use the Tcl built-in commands, and not those of the standard Tcl library (like `parray`), you will be fine. This is not a roadblock, just a matter of being aware. Whatever you want to do in your "checking function", is doable without.

Comment: Can you please help me out with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77036154/invalid-command-name-sqlite3-in-tcl-script-from-sqlite-docs-wapp-application? `parray` is valid command, but `sqlite3` is not in my case. How to add "sqlite's standard Tcl frontend" and should it help?