# invalid command name "sqlite3" in tcl script from sqlite docs (Wapp Application Error)

Tags: sqlite, tcl

I want to be able to use sqlite docs offline. I was glad this site https://www.sqlite.org/2023/sqlite-doc-3430000.zip had zip file with html docs. Zip even contained `search` file which turned out to be `tcl` script having: `#!/usr/bin/tclsh.docsrc...package require Tcl 8.6`; running as is failed, but I realized I do have `/usr/bin/tclsh8.6`. However now after `tclsh ./search` I've got in my browser

> Wapp Application Error
>
> invalid command name "sqlite3"
> while executing "sqlite3 db [file dir [wapp-param SCRIPT_FILENAME]]/search.d/search.db"
> (procedure "wapp-default" line 39)
> invoked from within "wapp-default"

Interestingly:

```
~/Downloads/sqlite-doc-3430000$ echo sqlite3 | tclsh
invalid command name "sqlite3"
~/Downloads/sqlite-doc-3430000$ tclsh
% sqlite3
SQLite version 3.37.2 2022-01-06 13:25:41
~/Downloads/sqlite-doc-3430000$ echo parray | tclsh
wrong # args: should be "parray a ?pattern?"
```

But I've noted second case just likely runs an external CLI commands.

How to install "sqlite's standard Tcl frontend, which gives you full Tcl and comes with Tcl distributions" (https://www.sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html), which was in the answer of [Sqlite (within SqliteStudio): invalid command name "parray"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49402066/sqlite-within-sqlitestudio-invalid-command-name-parray)? Any other ideas about cause of the error?

Added:

Web searching found some new related to `tcl` advice, after `apt-get install libsqlite3-dev / libsqlite3-tcl / tcl-dev` still no `sqlite3` command.

Added:

After comment by @mrcalvin + reading https://www.tcl.tk/community/tcl2004/Presentations/D.RichardHipp/slides/slides-all.html I tried to add `package require sqlite3` to "search" file and page opened. However after trying to use it I got (see below). Seems to me the code is not up-to-date or else. Don't know where to file a bug report...

> Wapp Application Error
>
> no such tokenizer: stoken
> while executing "db eval $sql"
> (procedure "searchresults" line 31)
> invoked from within "$cmd"
> ("uplevel" body line 1)
> invoked from within "uplevel {$cmd}"
> invoked from within "time [list uplevel $script]"
> (procedure "ttime" line 2)
> invoked from within "ttime {$cmd}"
> invoked from within "db transaction {
> set t [ttime {$cmd}]   }"
> (procedure "wapp-default" line 46)
> invoked from within "wapp-default"

Comment: Did you try loading the Tcl package: `$ tclsh` > `% package require sqlite3` > `% package req sqlite3` > `3.42.0` > `% info commands sqlite3` > `sqlite3`

Comment: @mrcalvin, thanks, after a while I understood what you meant and it worked. See Added to the question if curious. Now next issue with the code. I wonder how to contact devs / are they there and interested in fixing their code.

Comment: @mrcalvin, want to write an answer?

Comment: See my answer below, glad it helped. As for the other issue ("no such tokenizer"), better open a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before using the Tcl commands of the [`tclsqlite`](https://www.sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html) extension, you need to source the corresponding Tcl package:

1. Enter your Tcl shell:

---

```
$ tclsh
```

2. Enter the following Tcl command:

---

```
% package req sqlite3
3.42.0
```

3. Test the presence of tclsqlite commands:

---

```
% info commands sqlite3
sqlite3
% sqlite3 db1 :memory:
% db1 eval {select sqlite_version();}
3.42.0
% db1 close
```